# What is meant by ‘innocent of the adjustments’ here?

Tags: harper-lee, to-kill-a-mockingbird

> I could only look around me: Atticus and my Uncle, who went to school at home, knew everything - at least, what one didn’t the other did. Furthermore, I couldn’t help noticing that my father had served for years in the state legislature, **elected each time without opposition, innocent of the adjustments my teachers thought essential to the development of Good Citizenship. Jem educated on the half-Decimal half-Dunce-cap basis, seemed to function effectively alone or in a group, but Jem was a poor example: no tutorial system devised by man could have stopped him from getting at books.**

What do the lines in bold mean?

Comment: Hi Scarlett, just a couple of points you should know, since a few people have needed to edit your questions for formatting. You can format text as a **quote** by adding `>` at the start of a paragraph. And punctuation symbols such as `:` and `,` and `.` should always have a **space after them** ("... did. Furthermore, I ..." not "... did.Furthermore,I ...").

Answer (score 1):

**innocent** in this context means "without having encountered."

**adjustments** are "the corrections which teachers made" or "the lessons which the teachers thought were very important," even though clearly Atticus has achieved Good Citizenship without ever learning the specific curriculum or ideas which those teachers seemed to feel were critical.

Together, the entire sentence reads:

> I couldn’t help noticing that my father had served for years in the state legislature, elected each time without opposition, without ever having learned the specific ideas which my teachers insisted that I had to learn to be a Good Citizen.

Scout is slyly saying that the teachers' ideas of Good Citizenship were things she found boring and unnecessary — and is also probably referring to punishments or discipline she received because she wasn't conforming to their ideals.

The rest of the bolded section refers to her brother, and has nothing to do with Atticus.